# Disable keyboard in HTML SELECT tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, dom-events

I want to disable the keyboard for an HTML SELECT tag so the user can only use a mouse to select the options.

I've tried `event.cancelBubble=true` on the `onkeydown`, `onkeyup` and `onkeypress` events with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have to ask... why would you want to do this? It just hinders usability.

Comment: event.cancelBubble is not for preventing the default action. Its for preventing bubbling up of events.

Comment: My customer requires it as an extra level of security on a log in screen.  I tried to convince him it was pointless, but of course the customer is [nearly] always right.

Comment: I have to agree with DisguntledGoat, unless you have a very very good reason for doing this (and I can't imagine what that would be), this is a very bad idea.

Comment: I know it's a bad idea, but the person who's idea it was keeps a roof over my head.  Thank you all for your concern though.  I will my refer my customer to your comments and see if that changes his mind. :-)

Comment: It's really quite natural to want a non-keyboard based security feature, which prevents keystroke-captured logins from being re-played. You wouldn't normally do it in this way though. A better solution would be to change the order of the drop down list each time, which will mean a replayed key-stroke will select a different option. Another common solution is to ask for different things each time - for example the first and third letter from a password on one occasion and the fourth and last letter on another occasion.

Comment: I am doing exactly that - capturing random letters from a password using the alphabet in my drop down.  My customer is paranoid that the user's PC might have some keystroke sniffer on it though.

Comment: I have a similar need, but I have binding on the select using knockoutjs, so changing the value triggers an ajax request. and I have had a previous issue with the hosting provider that blocks the client if a lot of requests are bombarded,I know it may be an option I might be able to deal with in the server, but for the time being and just to prevent the rain of ajax calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone left me the correct answer and then removed it for some reason, so here it is:

```js
function IgnoreAlpha(e) {
  if (!e) {
    e = window.event;
  }
  if (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) // A to Z
  {
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancel = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <select id="MySelect" name="MySelect" onkeydown="IgnoreAlpha(event);">
    <option selected="selected " value=" " />
    <option value="A ">A</option>
    <option value="B ">B</option>
    <option value="C ">C</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Comment: I was going to say this doesn't work for me, but I needed to do use keydown instead of keyup. My use case is making my own keyboard selection function to handle choosing "John Zebraston" as opposed to "John Appleton".

Answer (score 2):

In a cross-browser way assuming that the event object has been properly initialized:

```
function disableKey(e)
{
   var ev = e ? e : window.event;

   if(ev)
   {
       if(ev.preventDefault)
          ev.preventDefault();
       else
         ev.returnValue = false;         
   }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
event.preventDefault()
```