# Stopping <select> from jumping to letter press

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

```
<select size="5">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
  <option>d</option>
  <option>e</option>
</select>
```

Naturally, when I press a, b, c, d, or e, this jumps to the option with that as the first letter. I need to disable this, preferably not through Javascript (not required).

Is there really no way to turn off this keypress jump to letter option?

Comment: Not without JavaScript, no. It's built into the control, I think at an OS level.

Comment: With Javascript how would it work?

Comment: Add a `keydown` handler and prevent the default action if the key is a letter? Sorry, I don't have time to write an answer, but that's what comes to mind.

Comment: I can think of no good reason to prevent the user from using a select element with the keyboard.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable keyboard in HTML SELECT tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227146/disable-keyboard-in-html-select-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it without JavaScript.

With JavaScript you will need to add an event handler for `keypress` event, to prevent default behavior and to stop propagation.

With jQuery:

```
$("select").on("keypress", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Take care that `$("select")` will select all your select inputs and you'll end up adding this `keypress` for all of them.

Without jQuery:

```
<select id="mySelect" size="5">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
  <option>d</option>
  <option>e</option>
</select>

var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
select.addEventListener ("keypress", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ep3xfyc8/9/

**Later edit: There exists a solution to achieve this without JavaScript. See Lee Kowalkowski's response below.**

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using JS to do this. @LeeKowalkowski's solution was pretty nifty but didn't work for my specific application.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do it **without** JavaScript.

Prefix every option with a [Zero-Width Non Joiner](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) character.

```html
<label for="select">Select:</label>
<select size="5" id="select">
  <option>&zwnj;a</option>
  <option>&zwnj;b</option>
  <option>&zwnj;c</option>
  <option>&zwnj;d</option>
  <option>&zwnj;e</option>
</select>
```

If this is going to be submitted in a HTTP request, the `&zwnj;` character should be ignored by the browser.  Every option should have its own `value` attribute for form submission purposes, anyway, and you would not need to put the `&zwnj;` character into the option values.

Comment: Nifty! Never seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

This is an adaption of what @razvan-dimitru proposes but keeping JS to a minimum. In a way, you only need markup for this solution:

```html
<select onkeyup='event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();'>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
  <option>d</option>
  <option>e</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't think cancelling the keyup event will cancel the keypress event.  I can still use the keyboard to change this select value.

Comment: Also this disables all keyboard events which need to be used in my use-case. Thank you though!

Answer (score -1):

Copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1227324

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function IgnoreAlpha(e)
{
    if (!e)
    {
        e = window.event ;
    }
    if (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) // A to Z
    {
        e.returnValue=false;
        e.cancel = true;
    }
}
</script>

<body>
    <p>
        <select id="MySelect" name="MySelect" onkeydown="IgnoreAlpha(event);"">
            <option selected="selected" value="" />
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    </body>
```